# a problem on homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

I am not getting a fact whether if $X\,\times\,Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y\,\times\,Y$ then is it true that $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$? Actually I want to know the result for say $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=[0,1)$.

Comment: You can deduce that the if ... then statement is false from your example. Clearly in that example $X$ isn't homeomorphic to $Y$, so you just have to show that $X \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y \times Y$ (which it is).

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, but apparently no, that is not true. For example, $\mathbb{R}^{\omega} \times \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ seems to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, both homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ but clearly, $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$. (Here $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is the countable product of $\mathbb{R}$ in the product topology.)

Comment: A slightly simpler example would be that $\{1\}\times\mathbb{N}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ but $\{1\}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

A more advanced example was given by Bing ([reference](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1970322)) and shows that the problem can be far more intrincate than a cardinality argument (whether of the spaces or the indexing set).